# How to get public profile details from profile url using linkedin Rest API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch whole information of user's by using linkedin public profile url But I am getting firstname, lastname and id in response.

How to get whole details.

I have tried on linkedin console

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=https%3a%2f%2fwww.linkedin.com%2fin%2fashishmishraoft?format=json

```
Response
{
  "firstName": "Ashish",
  "headline": "Sr PHP Developer at Myapp Generation.",
  "id": "STaDeFHBBN",
  "lastName": "Mishra"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LinkedIn does not return all possible member profile fields that are
>   available to you by default.  There is a limited selection of
>   additional member fields that are also available to you which may be
>   relevant to your application.  Refer to the Basic Profile Fields page
>   for a complete list of the basic member profile fields.
>
> The following example demonstrates how to customize your API call to
>   request specific member profile fields that you wish to be returned
>   during the Sign In with LinkedIn workflow:
>
> GET
>   `https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json`
>
> sample api response:

```
{
    "id": "1R2RtA",
    "numConnections": 42,
    "pictureUrl": "https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mprx/…"
}
```

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/signin-with-linkedin

Comment: How to get full details using 
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-url)?format=json

Answer (score 1):

you can't get full_profile information from the basic linked in api. In order to get full_profile information you have to become partener with linked in.

https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs

if you want to get full information of r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress , make get request to following url with access token

https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(email-address,id ,first-name ,last-name ,maiden-name ,formatted-name ,phonetic-first-name ,phonetic-last-name ,formatted-phonetic-name ,headline ,location ,industry ,current-share ,num-connections ,num-connections-capped ,summary ,specialties  ,positions ,picture-url ,picture-urls::(original) ,site-standard-profile-request ,api-standard-profile-request ,public-profile-url)?oauth2_access_token={YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN}&format=json